# Failed to instantiate module ui-mask angulajs with rquirejs

Tags: angularjs, masking

I need to mask my input in my application. I was using ngMask in angularjs. But i found an issue in ngMask is that if we update the mid value the cursor move to end. I tried to resolve the issue but did not find anything. Even on github this issue has reported but still not resolved. Here is the link
[ngMask Issue](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask/issues/78)

Then i decided to use another mask library. I found ui-mask and trying to use in my application but i am getting error when i include in my project. My application is in angularjs and i am using requirejs as well to load the modules.
This is what i have done in main.js:

```
paths: {
...////

        "angular-ui-mask": "../../lib/ui-mask/ui-mask.min",

    },

'angular-ui-mask': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angular-ui-mask'
        },
```

in app.js i have done:

```
var app = angular.module("app",
            [
                "ui.router",
                "mobile-angular-ui",
                "scrollable-table", //for alert triggering
                "rzModule", //slider for SEMI diagram
                "isteven-multi-select",
                "ui.bootstrap",
                "cgBusy", "dndLists", 'apm-kpi-widget',
                'angular.filter',
                "pascalprecht.translate",
                "jQueryScrollbar",
                "ui.checkbox",
                "angular-ui-mask"


            ])
```

This is exact i was doing for ngMask. But in this case i am getting error

```
[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4587
    at q (angular.js:322)
    at g (angular.js:4548)
    at bb (angular.js:4470)
    at c (angular.js:1746)
    at Object.yc [as bootstrap] (angular.js:1767)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angularAMD.js:449)
    at i (jquery-1.12.3.min.js?v=1531811705531:2)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.12.3.min.js?v=1531811705531:2)
```

What's the issue?

Comment: `ui-mask.min` -> `ui-mask.min.js`

Comment: as jsrouk said, unless you manually renamed the file, your link for it is wrong.

Comment: This is not the issue. I have put a debugger in ui-mask library. It is working fine.